# Display logo on shipping options for shopify

Tags: shopify

I'm implementing third party rates using the carrier service api for shopify. I've gotten to the point that I'm displaying the rates, and have also added delivery customization where I reorder the items. I'd also like to add branding (logo) to the carrier.

Any creative way to do this (without being on a plus plan)?